# How can I make it only redirect if it doesn't start from a specific php file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to write a condition on the .htaccess file that should always redirect to the checkAuth.php file, except when the request is started via the `header ("Location: ..")` from the checkAuth.php.

.htaccess and checkAuth.php are in the same directory.

I have already tried to output the file directly with `readfile("..")` instead of `header("Location: ..")`, but the headers could not be read reliably with `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)`.

Also, I tried this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$`
`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^/checkAuth.php$`